# SQL Server Linked Server To MySQL "Too many connections"

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

I have attempted to find the answer here and via Google on how to control connections for a linked server ODBC connection.

***Overview***

I have a linked server from SQL Server 2014 to MySQL for the purposes of extracting data for our data warehouse.  I've queried the database quite a few times without issue.  Then yesterday, suddenly the query to read from the table is slow, and then I get reports that the application using this MySQL database are getting a "too many connections" error.

***Details***

The following query selects the data from MySQL and inserts to the SQL Server table.

```
INSERT INTO tmpCustomers
    (fieldlist)
SELECT 
    myc.contact_id,
    myl.franchise_id,
    myl.lead_source,
    LEFT(RTRIM(myc.first_name) + ' ' + RTRIM(myc.last_name),100) AS Name,
    myc.first_name,
    myc.last_name,
    myc.company,
    myc.Email,
    myc.primary_phone,
    myc.home_phone,
    myc.mobile_phone,
    myc.work_phone,
    myc.fax,
    myc.address1,
    myc.Address2,
    myc.City,
    myc.[state],
    myc.zip_code,
    myc.created_date,
    myc.updated_date
FROM [MYSQLDB]...[franchise] myf
INNER JOIN  [MYSQLDB]...[leads] myl
    ON myl.franchise_id = myf.franchise_id
INNER JOIN  [MYSQLDBE]...[contact] myc
    ON myc.contact_id = myl.contact_id
```

This query returns about 200K rows of data, and will grow.  The MySQL database is used by our customer base, and this is a back-end process to pull data into our data warehouse.

The query has been working without issue over the past week of testing, until yesterday, where it caused our MySQL support to restart the MySQL server twice.

The ODBC setup was done using the "mysql-connector-odbc-5.3.6-win64.msi" version.  I don't find any settings there to limit the number of connections.  ODBC does show "Allow multiple statements", which this is not.  It also has "Enable automatic reconnect", which I can't imagine why for a single query would be needed.

***Summary***

I can't afford to stop customers from connecting, and need to disable the process from using too many connections when doing the import.

Any input on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

KDS

Update: 2016-Oct-05

AWS server - M3.xlarge
4 CPU
15 GiB
2 40 GiB SSD drives

Answer (score 0):

It's better to optimize the MySQL server if you can't afford to stop customers from connecting.

With this much information, it hard to optimize or suggest something for MySQL optimization.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html

Better to update your configuration file. Or max_connections limit and InnoDB variable if you are using innoDB. And RAM also.

Can you update the above information in question section.

Comment: I am trying to get some of this information from my network guys.  I work on the SQL Servers and not really MySQL.  This is the first project trying to get data from it.  The MySQL Workbench>Management>Client Connections shows "Connection Limit": 250.  A 3rd party company has been managing this server, though it is housed internally.  There suggestion was to copy the database to another database on the same server, and connect to that.  That seems like it will still be using connections from the server.  Are they server level, or database level connections?

Comment: It is server level connections, MySQL does not work on schema level. How  many query is executed per minute. Also check "show processlist" in MySQL

Comment: Thanks khalid

I'm working to get that access.  If I run "show processlist" I only see my connections and not those of others.  I'll update the question as soon as I have some better access.

Also forgive my grammatical typo above.  "Their* suggestion..." is what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to mark this as answered as it's been about a year and no real solution to it.  The issue was locks on the MySQL server as the SQL Server linked server was reading the data.  SQL Server arguments like NOLOCK had no impact on resolving this.

So, what was done was to take a backup of the MySQL database nightly and restore it to a separate database that we linked to for SQL Server, and process the data from there.  The reads are usually done in a matter of a minute or two.  SQL Server was still putting a lock on the MySQL table, and users then started to stack multiple connections until all the connections to MySQL were used up.

So, since I only needed the data for reporting purposes daily, this separate database copy worked, but I don't know of any other fix to this.

Thanks

KD